# Dired+ on dark color themes

Tags: emacs

As far as I know, Dired and Dired+ work better by default (give better color contrast) on color themes with clear backgrounds. I know I can customize face colors on Dired+ for Emacs  manually using `M-x customize-face`, but this can be tedious when customizing multiple faces one by one.

Given this, I was wondering if anybody knows of a code snippet that automatically customizes those faces that don't work well on dark themes such as [Zenburn](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/04/zenburn-color-theme.html) or [Tango](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/color-theme-tango.el).

I am mostly interested on a solution for Dired+, but I wonder if a solution exists for Bookmarks+ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the [`background-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html#Font-and-Color-Parameters) frame parameter of your frames is set correctly (to `dark`).

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-mode . dark))
```

This may not be enough as some modes use additional faces whose default value doesn't depend on `default-frame-alist`. After you've done that, use `list-faces-display` to see what faces have poor contrast, and add lines like these to your `.emacs`:

```
(set-face-background 'something-face "SomeDarkColor")
(set-face-foreground 'something-face "SomeLightColor")
```

Comment: How can I apply my main color theme, monokai, to dired+ buffers?